# height 'h' in integration

Tags: integration

I was looking back at some work regarding integration that I covered at school and uncovered this photo.

[image]

It was a photo of our teacher proving to use the integration using the trapeziums.

Now something bugged me.

I remember reading this formula

$$h = \frac{b-a}{n}$$

but I remember many times being told that this formula isn't really a good idea.

For many years this still bugged me to this day because I couldn't remember why this formula isn't really a good approximation for the width of the bar.

Jokingly, my teacher used to call it "Satan's formula", but my question is, if anyone follows the same principle:

*Why isn't this formula good to use?*

Comment: I can't see any reason that this simple formula would be called "Satan's formula". The only thing I can think of is that the formula assumes all subintervals have the same width, and this might not be ideal.

Comment: You want your definite integral to give the same value no matter how you partition your interval. That's part of being (Riemann) integrable

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch when would you need adaptive step size?

Answer (score 1):

If you are splitting your segment $[a,b]$ that has length $b-a$ into $n$ equal segments, then each segment has length $h=\frac{b-a}{n}$. I don't see why this may be a bad idea.

Maybe.... because, the integral is actually equal to the limit of Riemann sums over the partitions as  the norm of the partition is going to $0$ (if this limit exist).

So, a function is integrable if this limit over all partitions exist, not just uniform partitions. And I think there may be a function (of course this is not going to be continuous) where the limit over uniform partitions exist(i.e. the trapezium approximation actually converges to something), but the integral doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is fine to use and is actually one of the ways to define integration over the real number line (granted, it doesn’t work for all functions but it’s “good enough”). I’m not sure why it would’ve been called satan’s formula at all — perhaps because it’s only an approximation, not an exact result? Or maybe because you can vary n in the formula? I’d only encourage using it when you have a computer handy though and you can’t integrate the original expression as otherwise it’s pretty time consuming and useless.